# Can not launch older Minecraft versions than 1.13

Tags: java, minecraft

my distro is Ubuntu 19.10. I can not launch older Minecraft installations than 1.13. The game instantly crushes on the launch. Here is an Imgur link to the picture of the crash message:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/BhcUJ3M]

And here are some imgur links to the pictures of 1.8.9 (installation I want to launch) installation and what happens when I browse Java executable (I think the problem is with Java)

[image: https://imgur.com/a/1xrbvpe]

[image: https://imgur.com/a/Wde7h4s]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The problem is that older versions of Minecraft run on Java 8 so I had to change the default version of Java. If you type this command in the terminal you should see your current version of Java:

```
java -version
```

The way to change it is to write this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This will open a menu like this:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection Path...
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java...
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java...
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java...
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java...

Press <enter> to keep...[*], or type selection number:
```

Then, enter the number of the selection of the java version you want and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. For example, if I want Java 7 I will type `1`.